# Why do I receive this ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, html

`ReferenceError: array is not defined`

I've been trying to add click event listeners to multiple buttons but when I run it in the console it gives me the referenceError above.

Below is my javascript code:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".save");
console.log(array);

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("forEach worked");
  });
});
```

I have looked at other questions on StackOverFlow for an answer, but they basically all say that I should put the  tag at that the end of the html body so that the html can load before. I tried this and it doesn't work still.

Here is my html code for reference:

```
<body>
    <div class="Container1">
        <li class="dropdown">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu--animated">
              </li>
              <a class="dropdown-items" href="equiptment.html">Equiptment</a> <a class="dropdown-items" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
              <a class="dropdown-items" href="trails.html">Trails</a><a class="dropdown-items" href="signup.html">Sign Up</a><a class="dropdown-items" href="saveForLater.html">Saved For Later</a><a class="dropdown-items" href="/index.html">Back to Menu</a>
              
            </li>
            </ul>
            Hiking</li>
          </div>
          
          <div class="text-container">
          
        </div>

        <h1 class="trails-head">Trails</h1>
        <h2 class="trails-h2">One of the things that makes hiking so exciting is endless options of trails you can take,each each is a very different experience. Hiking is also an incredible way to keep fit while discoering new places. Additionally it is a very social activity and is an amazing activity for friends, work colleagues or any other group.</h2>
        <h3 class="trails-h3">Different Terrain</h3>
        <h4 class="trails-h4">With different terrain comes a different experience. But it also comes with different preparations and equiptment. With a dry and rocky hike it is better to wear good hiking boots with decent grip. You could also bring a walking stick to help with stability in the more difficult patches of the hike. If you are planning hiking in a snowy and frozen climate it is of course better to wear hiking boots with ice grip or spikes. It is of course going to be colder and then it is smart to pack some warm but lightweight clothes.</h4>
        
        
        <div class="tableDiv">
        <h5 class="trails-h5">South African Hikes</h4>
            
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>Trails</th>
              <th>Province</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Lion's Head</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Pipe Track</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Skeleton Gorge</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Table Mountain</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">King Fisher Trail</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Robberg Peninsula</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Diep Walle Forest Walk</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
          
          <!-- <input class="radio" type="submit">Radio</input> -->
          
          <img class="trails-img" src="/norway.jpeg">
          <img src="hiking7.jpg" class="hiking7"  />
          <p class="newsletter">Sign up to our news letters at the bottom of the this page</p>
          <div class="radio-div">
            <label>Age</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="under_13" name="user_age"><label><label for="under_13" class="light">Under 13</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="over_13" name="user_age"><label><label for="under_13" class="light">Over 13</label><br> 
            <label>Gender</label><br> 
            <input type="radio" id="under_13" name="user_gender"><label><label for="under_13" class="light">Male</label> <br> 
            <input type="radio" id="under_13" name="user_gender"><label><label for="under_13" class="light">Female</label> <br> 
            <label>Sign up to news letter</label> <br> 
            <input type="radio" id="under_13" name="newsletter"><label><label for="under_13" class="light">Yes</label> <br> 
            <input type="radio" id="under_13" name="newsletter"><label><label for="under_13" class="light">No</label> <br> 
            <label>Recieve emails of new trails and hikes</label> <br> 
            <input type="radio" id="under_13" name="recieve-emails"><label><label for="under_13" class="light">Yes</label> <br> 
            <input type="radio" id="under_13" name="recieve-emails"><label><label for="under_13" class="light">No</label> <br> 
          </div>
          <script src="saveForLater.js"></script>
        </body>
```

Comment: where do you define array variable in console.log(array);

Comment: Well, you never defined any variable named `array`. Maybe you wanted to write `console.log(buttons)` in your 2nd line.

Comment: because, if this is all you code, array is effectively not defined. You never declared it. Maybe you wanna write console.log(buttons);

Comment: Ah great. How embarrassing.  Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is console.logging an array object, that doesn't exist. After deleting the line, ReferenceError shouldn't be a problem.